# Shared variables between php $_GET and $POST

Tags: php, global-variables

Why page can not get the `$temp_kt` value? I tested `$_SESSION['temp_kt']` and `$_ENV['temp_kt']`, neither worked.

```
<?php
$temp_kt=0;
if(isset($_POST['db']))
{
    if($_POST['db']=="feedback")
    {
        global $temp_kt;
    $temp_kt=$_POST['temp_kt'];
    }
    exit();
}
if(isset($_GET['q']))
{
    echo "temp_kt=".$temp_kt;
}
?>
```

Comment: How could this ever print anything? The code that sets `$temp_kt` also exits!

Comment: First of all why you need a `global` keyword there?

Answer (score 3):

You have exit in `if(isset($_POST['db']))` which mean that you can't have both if statements. If you want to save that value in session you should use code like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['db'])) {
    if ($_POST['db']=="feedback") {
         $_SESSION['temp_kt'] = $_POST['temp_kt'];
    }
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    echo "temp_kt=" . $_SESSION['temp_kt'];
}
?>
```

**session_start** function will enable session for you, you need it at the begining when you set and get session values (it will send cookie to the browser - using header - so you can't have any echo before).

Comment: Point him out that he needs `session_start()` at the top else he will post another question in 10 mins saying udefined `$_SESSION` var

Comment: @Mr.Alien written info about `session_start()` function

Comment: @jcubic yea, better now ;)